# changing default names for infopath forms in custom workflow

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, rename

in SPD when infopath is used to customize the task init. form the names are picked which are not at all helpful. IS there a way to rename these from either Infopath or Sharepoint or SPD?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the name of the form that is submitted.
To do this goto `Tools -> Data Connections`.

If you have a dataconnection already set up for form submission then you can modify that one otherwise set up a new one.

I will assume that you need to set up an new sharepoint document library data connection that you will submit to.

In `Tools-> Data Connections`

1. click the Add button
2. Create a new connection to Submit Data
3. select To a document library on a sharepoint site.
4. this next page should have the Document library and the File name that you want to specify.
   If however you want the ability to set the filename based on data in the form then at the end of the file name textbox there is a button with Fx as the text (infopath function expression)  Click on this button.
5. it will bring up a Insert Formula dialog box.  It is here that you can specify that name of the form based on some criteria with in the form.